# Importing backend App with Tkinter - Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have written a tkinter app that sends a file to the imported backend app for processing upon clicking the "convert" button.  While running the GUI I see that the backend app runs but when I click the button I get this error: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/import'

I think it is because when importing, the backend app runs in the background so when the button is clicked I cannot open an already opened application.  Is this true?  IS there a way to set up the GUI so the backend application only runs when I click the button?

```
import os
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import EE_Import

content = ''
file_path = ''

def subMenu():
    pass

def get_previous_provider(event):
    print('Paychex')

def get_platform_list(event):
    return('Flex')

def import_list(event):
    print('Employee Import')

def open_file():
    global content
    global file_path

    filename = askopenfilename()
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    content = infile.read()
    file_path = os.path.dirname(filename)
    locEntry.delete(0, END)
    locEntry.insert(0, file_path)
    return content

def convert():
    x = locEntry.get()  #sends file name to EE_Import to process
    EE_Import_Paychex_Flex.open_sesame(x)





root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Import")

# ---- Menu Line
menuLine = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menuLine)

# ---- File Submenu
fileMenu = Menu(menuLine)
menuLine.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Help", command=subMenu)
fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)

# ---- Browse Button to select where your file is
browseButton = Button(root, text="Browse", command=open_file)
browseButton.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2, pady=2)

file_path = StringVar()
locEntry = Entry(root, textvariable=file_path, width=40)
locEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)

# ---- List that allows the user to select their options out of what is available
provList = Listbox(root, width=50)
provList.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=2, pady=2, columnspan=3)
provList.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', get_previous_provider)

# ---- Button that will start the conversion process
goButton = Button(root, text="Convert", command=convert)
goButton.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=2, pady=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can open the same file more than once as long as you are only reading. But I dont think you can if you have opened a file with read/write tag.

Comment: please show the full error rather than trying to paraphrase it. We need to know what line is causing the error.

Comment: thanks.  I think I have it figured out.  I am getting a new error now more related to linking the backend to the frontend.  for some reason it is not passing the variable to the backend function which then tells the backend application which file to use to run with.  I'll have to fill out another question after i tinker some more with it.  thanks!